# how to plot NA gaps using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In basic plotting in R if there is an NA in a data series ggplot2 a gap will be plotted:

As an example see:

```
df=data.frame(x=c(1:10),y=c(1:10))
df[5:7,]=NA
plot(df,type="l")
```

However, ggplot2 removes the missing values and plots a straight line
with no gap.

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x,y))+geom_line()
```

I'd like to keep the gaps. They are valuable info in the data I am working with.
Is there a simple way to tell ggplot2 to stop ignoring gaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `geom_line` with `geom_path`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_path()
```

[image]

Comment: Works even without specifying na.rm = TRUE. "geom_path()" also works.

Comment: Thanks, This is what I needed.

na.rm seems to be related verbosity, but not really a flag for na.rm. See output of ?geom_path:

  "na.rm: If ‘FALSE’ (the default), removes missing values with a
          warning.  If ‘TRUE’ silently removes missing values."

Answer (score 4):

This happens because you set *both*  x and y to `NA`. (And the ggplot2 behaviour is more sensible IMHO than the base plot behaviour.)  If only the y values are `NA`, you get the desired behaviour. Here is a workaround:

```
df$g <- cumsum(apply(df, 1, anyNA))
ggplot(data=df,aes(x,y, group=g))+geom_line()
```

[image: resulting graph]

Comment: Thanks Roland. This is useful. Combining both answers i.e. using geom_path and the group= tag, I get an even better solution to my problem.