# How to plot NA gaps in ggplot2 using stat_summary with geom = "line"?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to plot data containing NAs as "gaps" in `stat_summary` with `geom = "line"`?

It is feasible for `geom_line()` by using `geom_path()` instead
(see [how to plot NA gaps using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140004/how-to-plot-na-gaps-using-ggplot2) and [How to plot data containing NA's as "gaps" in geom_line](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ggplot2/cA4Q3aM01fU/Yz1qMppJroU)).

MWE building on the example from @stuttungr (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140004/how-to-plot-na-gaps-using-ggplot2))

```
    df = data.frame( x = c(1:10), y = c(1:10) )
    df[5:7, ]=NA

    # get NO gap as expected
    ggplot(data=df, aes(x,y)) +
      geom_point(color = "green", size = 5) +
      geom_line()
```

[image: geom_line]

```
    # get the gap as expected
    ggplot(data=df, aes(x,y)) +
      geom_point(color = "green", size = 5) +
      geom_path()
```

[image: geom_path]

```
    # get NO gap unfortunately
    ggplot(data=df, aes(x,y)) +
      geom_point(color = "orange", size = 5) +
      stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line")
```

[image: stat_summary_with_line]

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a column for `group`

```
ggplot(data = transform(df, group = with(rle(is.na(df$x)), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))),
       aes(x, y, group = group)) +
    geom_point(color = "orange", size = 5) +
    stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line")
```

[image]

Here's the `data`

```
transform(df, group = with(rle(is.na(df$x)), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)))
#    x  y group
#1   1  1     1
#2   2  2     1
#3   3  3     1
#4   4  4     1
#5  NA NA     2
#6  NA NA     2
#7  NA NA     2
#8   8  8     3
#9   9  9     3
#10 10 10     3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @d.b for the quick solution! Would you also have a fix for tricking ggplot2 into adding a gap in the plot if the data was `df = data.frame(x = c(1:5,7:10), y = c(1:5,7:10))`? Neither geom_path() nor your proposal seems to solve this similar case.

Comment: @mavericks, you need to figure out a way to add `group`. For that case, you could use `transform(df, group = cumsum(c(1, diff(df$x) != 1)))`

Comment: So for a given line, I would have to check whether there are gaps in the line. And then based on the gap(s) assign parts of the line different values of the `group` variable. The tricky part is that I have a plot with 6 facets (for the different levels of `factorA`), and in each facet there are 7 lines (for the different levels of `factorB`). Adding the `group`  variable to my long df is, therefore, a little challenge.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table::rleid` is convenient for these cases :

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group=data.table::rleid(is.na(x)))) +
  geom_point(color = "orange", size = 5) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line")
#> Warning: Removed 3 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary).
#> Warning: Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]